# Scraping data instagram - Unusual Login Attempt alert

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, nodes, puppeteer

I'm junior developer and i'm trying to build a bot. My bot can access instagram by my account and follow my friends. However I'm getting this problem.

[image: screenshot]

I'm using nodejs including puppeteer package. Thanks for you help with my problem.

```
const robotic = async (req, res) => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
  await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login');
  await page.waitForSelector('input[name="username"]');
  await page.waitForSelector('input[name="password"]');
  await page.waitForSelector('button[type="submit"]');
  await page.type('input[name="username"]', process.env.USERNAME);
  await page.type('input[name="password"]', process.env.PASSWORD);
  await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.waitFor(6000)
  await browser.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in your code itself, Instagram is telling you what's happening, let's examine it:

- you are writing a Puppeteer bot that accesses your Instagram profile
- you run and re-run and re-run your script while you're writing the Puppeteer script
- since Puppeteer is a standard browser, Instagram treat this kind of accesses as standard user login tries
- so much login tries in a limited time could be suspicious (what kind of standard user tries to log in to Instagram ten times in a couple of minutes?)
- so Instagram, protecting your account, prevents any additional login tries and wants you to verify that you aren't a malicious bot or a user that has stolen your password

Probably you get the same error from Instagram if you manually open an incognito page, you log in, you close the page and you re-do the same.

Not all sites allow you to build bots that consumes them and they do that to protect the users

Comment: Thanks for your reply so much. I got it now.

Comment: Nice  do you need anything more? Otherwise, accept my answer, it could be helpful to other users 

Answer (score 0):

You can use prompts library and check if there is a security form. If there is it will trigger prompt in console where you can type the code from sms or whatever. Here is a sample below:

```
        let isSecurity = await page.$$("form.JraEb");

        if (isSecurity[0]) {
            isSecurity = await page.$$("form.JraEb button");

            await isSecurity[0].click();

            // await instagram.page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

            await page.waitFor(1100);

            const response = await prompts({
                type: "text",
                name: "value",
                message: "Code?",
            });

            await page.waitFor("form input");

            const input = await page.$$("form input");

            await input[0].click();

            await page.type("form input", response.value, {
                delay: 114,
            });

            const button = await page.$$("form button");

            await button[0].click();

            await page.waitForNavigation({
                waitUntil: "networkidle2",
            });

            await page.waitFor("input[placeholder='Search']");

        } else {
            await page.waitFor("input[placeholder='Search']");
        }
```

Also, you can save cache, so that you will not go through login process each time